# Esperanto as an official language of a nation

Tags: language

I know of two attempts to introduce Esperanto as an official language of a micro-nation: *Neutral Moresnet* (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moresnet_ne%C5%ADtrala) and *Insulo de la Rozoj* (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulo_de_la_Rozoj). Does anybody know of any other cases?